# Run a task every 5 minutes but not between Monday 9 on to Thursday 1pm

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run a program on Linux every 5 minutes throughout the week but don't want to run it between Monday 9pm to Thursday 1 pm.

My current cronjob:

```
*/5 * * * * my script
```

This runs every 5 minutes. But how can I modify it not to run between Monday 9pm to Thursday 1 pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup three cron jobs:

```
*/5 * * * 5,6,7 my script # Run every 5 minutes on days Friday Saturday and Sunday

*/5 0-9 * * 1  my script # Run every 5 minutes between the hours of 12 midnight and 9 am on Monday

*/5 13-0 * * 4 my script # Run every 5 minutes between the hours of 1pm to 12am on Thursday/Friday
```